# How do i print only the count of the positive numbers in an input?

Tags: python

In my code, i want to only count the positive numbers from a user input and print it. So far i can print only the positive numbers but i couldn't print how many positive numbers there are

my code:

```
num = map(float, input().split())
for post in num:
    if post > 0:
        print(int(post))
```

input:

```
2 -4 3.6 1
```

Output:

```
2
3
1
```

the output i want:

```
3 (the number of positive numbers)(regardless of decimals)
```

any advice? I've tried getting the length of 'post' but it returns an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the following code.

```py
print(len([i for i in num if i > 0]))
```

---

### How it works

The above method uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is equivalent to:

```py
result = []

for i in num:
    if i > 0:
        result.append(i)

print(len(result))
```

The list `result` that we get is the list of positive numbers.

```py
>>> print(result)
[2, 3.6, 1]
```

And then we will use `len` to count the number of elements in the list.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. But i want to know the logic behind the code?

Comment: @kianclark Ok, I will explain it in the next few edits.

Comment: @kianclark I have explained the code a bit more clearly. If there is anything you still don't understand, you could ask me here.

Comment: what is the 'append' statement?

Comment: We use `append()` to add the element `i` at the end of the list `result`. You can read more about append [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp).

Comment: oh, thanks! i understand it now